# facebook friends invitation dialog embedded in the page

Tags: facebook

How can i get facebook friends invitation dialog embedded my page?

i.e. http://apps.facebook.com/promotionshq/contests/96234/invites/new

unlike other dialog boxes it should open in the same window.

How it can be done using Javascript SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include a "display" parameter for any dialog to indicate the type you want. But Facebook will always use a separate window if it decides it is "insecure". You can provide an access token, or have the user already authenticated to display inline.

"iframe: Display the dialog in a lightbox iframe on the current page. Because of the risk of clickjacking, this is only allowed for some certain dialogs, and requires you to pass a valid access_token."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/